# How can I add '€' in extjs?

Tags: extjs

All is in the question, is there a way to display the € symbol in extjs?
I tried

```
var euroMoney = function(v) {
            v = (Math.round((v - 0) * 100)) / 100;
            v = (v == Math.floor(v)) ? v + ".00" : ((v * 10 == Math.floor(v * 10)) ? v + "0" : v);
            v = String(v);
            var ps = v.split('.'),
                whole = ps[0],
                sub = ps[1] ? ',' + ps[1] : ',00',
                r = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
            while (r.test(whole)) {
                whole = whole.replace(r, '$1' + '.' + '$2');
            }
            v = whole + sub;

            return v + " â‚¬";
        }
```

But for euroMoney(1) it returns me

```
1,00 Ã¢â€šÂ¬
```

Comment: Use a better text editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens when your text editor saves it the wrong way. Make sure the encoding in your text editor is set to `UTF-8` and you should be fine.